# Call to undefined function mysqli_result()

Tags: php, mysqli

I have problem with `mysqli_result()` -> (ex `mysql_result`)

My code:

```
$per_page = 6;
$pages_query = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users');  
$pages = ceil(mysqli_result($pages_query, 0) / $per_page);
```

browser error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_result() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bootstrap/pagination.php on line 11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As opposed to [`mysql_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php), there's no `mysqli_result()` function available in `MySQLi`.

Use [`mysqli_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) function to get the total number of rows. Your code should be like this:

```
$per_page = 6;
$pages_query = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users'); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($pages_query);
$pages = ceil($row[0] / $per_page);
```